# Collapse SectionList section with animation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I am usung `react-native` `SectionList` to display sectioned data (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist). I added ability to collapse/expand sections on section header tap like:

```js
const section1Collapsed, setSection1Collapsed = useState(false);

const getListData = useMemo(() => {
  let data = [];

  if (section1Data && section1Data.length) {
    data.push({
      title: 'Section 1',
      data: section1Collapsed ? [] : section1Data,
    });
  }
  if (section2Data && section2Data.length) {
    data.push({
      title: 'Section 2',
      data: section2Data,
    });
  }

  return data;
}, [section1Data, section2Data, section1Collapsed]);
```

and then I use these data in `SectionList`:

```js
<SectionList
  sections={getListData}
  ...restSectionListProps
/>
```

It works, but I wonder if there is any possibility to animate collapsing? 
I added

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
  }, [section1Collapsed]);
```

And when I expand a section, it is animated. But when I want to collapse, there is no animation (which is normal for me, because I render section without data). Do you have any ideas how to add animation on collapse?